# How to quantify a specify amount in logic

Tags: logic

I'm looking for a way to specify the number of times an event happens in a Discourse Representation Structure, basically using first order predicate logic. I have the existential and universal quantifiers available, but I'm looking for a way to say for example that an event or state happens a 100 times, not just always or sometimes. I'm thinking set theory might help, but I'm not sure how. Any tips?

Comment: Exactly 100 or up to 100?

Comment: Interesting, never heard of [Discourse Representation Theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/discourse-representation-theory/), is this what you're referring to? tl;dr does this introduce new connectives and/or quantifiers, or can it sufficiently effectively be defined in terms of syntax of classical predicate logic.

Comment: Yes DRT is what I'm referring to. It's essentially definable in terms of predicate logic. As for you question naslundx: at least 100.

Answer (score 1):

There exist at least two things with the property $P$:
$$\exists x\exists y(Px\land Py\land x\ne y).$$

There exist at least three things with the property $P$:
$$
\exists x\exists y\exists z(Px\land Py\land Pz\land x\ne y\land x\ne z\land y\ne z).
$$
...

There exist *exactly* two things with the property P:
$$\exists x\exists y(Px\land Py\land x\ne y)\land\lnot\exists x\exists y\exists z(Px\land Py\land Pz\land x\ne y\land x\ne z\land y\ne z).$$
...

Comment: For *exactly* two, you could also use  $\exists x\exists y\forall z(Px\wedge Py\wedge x\ne y\wedge(Pz\to(z=x\vee z=y)))$